# Countable $\sigma$-finite measure dominated by a probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. Let $\left\{ \mu_{n}\right\} _{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of finite measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Then there exists a probability measure $\lambda$ such that $\mu_{n}\ll\lambda$. For example, we can consider $$\lambda(\cdot)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\frac{\mu_{n}(\cdot)}{\mu_{n}(\Omega)}}.$$

What is we extend it to the case where $\left\{ \mu_{n}\right\} _{n\geq1}$ are $\sigma$-finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you show that $\mu_n <<\nu_n$ for  some finite measure $\nu_n$ for each $n$. Then you can find  a p.m. $\lambda$ with $\nu_n <<\lambda$ for all $n$ which implies $\mu_n <<\lambda$ for all $n$.

So consider any sigma finite measure $\mu$. There exist disjoint sets $A_n$ such that $\mu(A_n) <\infty$ for all $n$ and $\bigcup_n A_n=\Omega$. Let $\nu(E)=\sum \frac 1 {2^{n}} \frac {\mu_n(E\cap A_n)} {1+\mu_n( A_n)}$. This gives a finite measure $\nu$ with $\mu <<\nu$.

Comment: But here I have countable $\sigma$-finite measures. How to construct $A_n$ for all $\mu _n$

Comment: You don 't have to. It is enough to show that each $\mu_n$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. some finite measure. Once this is done you can apply the case you already know to find your p.m. $\lambda$. In finding $\nu_n$ from $\mu_n$ for fixed $n$ the sets $A_1,A_2,...$ can depend on $n$. @Joesf.Albert

Comment: I see your point, Wonderful Answer! Many thanks!

Comment: There is a slight error in your construction. It should be $v\left(E\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\frac{\mu\left(A_{n}\cap E\right)}{1+\mu\left(A_{n}\right)}$

Comment: @Joesf.Albert That was  serious typo indeed. Thanks for pointing it out.